# Is it ok to edit svn Tag instead of svn branch for this situation

Tags: svn, versioning

App version 1 is in UAT. Development is currently being done for version 2 of app. There are urgent uat fixes needed for App version 1.

Is it ok just to edit the latest tag version used for UAT deployment to implement the fixes? or do we go for the "longer" way which is branch the tag number used for the uat release, then let the developers work on that branch and use that for the UAT fixes deployment.

Answer (score 1):

no. keep your tags immutable.
branch at that tag and tag the new release as 1.1

Comment: Yes. As you know the tag is the same as a branch. you could totally add too it.  It's just going to get confusing.  Imagine if you have several test environments... which version 1.0 is installed?   It's trivial easy to branch at the tag and retag.